# HelloMapView problem

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm  a new Android developer and I have been trying to get the HelloMapView example to work properly.
I got the API Key for debug following:
http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

I get the application running both in the emulator and on a mobile phone, but in  both cases, I only see the overlay item of the example but I can't see the map.
I have already done this twice and the result is the same.
I have declared the use of the library and the use of internet permisson in the manifest.

Do you have any idea for solving my problem?

Comment: You see an overlay item them you added as an example and you see the map?  So, what exactly, is not working?

Comment: -1 for we have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: Hello thank you for your time, let me explain my self better.
I tried to implement the HelloMap example.
The example runs, it should show me the map and the overlay item in Mexico City. I can see the overlay item, but not the map, I mean, I only see a gray grid where it supose to be a map.

Comment: have you added your key at the right place in the xml file? double check that, maybe a copy&paste problem only...

Comment: Also check the log for errors from MapView.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED, I  had a mistake in the Manifest.
This is the right one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    <activity android:name=".HelloMapView"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Thank you every one :D